# How to get data from single file component to display differently across my application

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to vuejs so please bear with me!

I have made a simple component where i pass data to it from my application, but i want to be able to play with the HTML when i reuse the component throughout my app. I have simplified everything down to make things easier, here is my .vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :data="data">This is a placeholder ({{data}})</slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'test',
  props: {
    data: {}
  }
}
</script>
```

And in my php file i have entered the following:

```
<test :data = "'testData'">
    <template slot-scope="prop">    
        {{ prop.data }}
    </template>
</test>
```

The problem is that when it renders it just displays {{ prop.data }} on my page and if i remove {{ prop.data }} it renders: This is a placeholder (testData).

What am i doing wrong! Or is it not possible to do what i am doing without creating another .vue file that uses the reusable component i have created?

Answer (score 0):

by putting `{{ prop.data }}` between

```
<template slot-scope="prop">{{ prop.data }}</template>
```

Vue replace the slot in `test.vue` file by `{{ prop.data }}` and when you remove `{{ prop.data }}` from template you are saying render the slot content which is `This is a placeholder ({{data}})`

Comment: But my expected result should be:

testData when i include {{ prop.data }}

But instead i am just getting :

{{ prop.data }}

Which seems like Vue is not picking up that its a variable that needs rendering

Comment: I just tried with your code and i was getting correct output i.e. testData. below is the link you can compare. Maybe typo issue in code recheck please https://codesandbox.io/s/p9vq8qry57

Comment: But you have the template code inside a .vue file where as i have mine in a php file. Does this matter?  so `<test :data = "'testData'">
    <template slot-scope="prop">    
        {{ prop.data }}
    </template>
</test>` is in my php code to render html so i can pass a php var into it.

Comment: Playing with the code i would assume i would have to create another component that extends the base component to change how parts look with slots.